# Python replace unprintable characters except linebreak

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii, python-re, non-printing-characters

I am trying to write a function that replaces unprintable characters with space, that worked well but it is replacing linebreak `\n` with space too. I cannot figure out why.

Test code:

```
import re

def replace_unknown_characters_with_space(input_string):
    # Replace non-printable characters (including escape sequences) with spaces
    # According to ChatGPT, \n should not be in this range
    cleaned_string = re.sub(r'[^\x20-\x7E]', ' ', input_string)

    return cleaned_string

def main():
    test_string = "This is a test string with some unprintable characters:\nHello\x85World\x0DThis\x0Ais\x2028a\x2029test."
    
    print("Original String:")
    print(test_string)
    
    cleaned_string = replace_unknown_characters_with_space(test_string)
    
    print("\nCleaned String:")
    print(cleaned_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
Original String:
This is a test string with some unprintable characters:
Hello
Thisd
is 28a 29test.

Cleaned String:
This is a test string with some unprintable characters: Hello World This is 28a 29test.
```

As you can see, the linebreak before Hello World is replaced by space, which is not intended. I tried to get help from ChatGPT but its regex solutions don't work.

my last resort is to use a for loop and use python built-in `isprintable()` method to filter the characters out, but this will be much slower compared to regex.

Comment: aside; if you meant to have UTF-8 space characters in that string then should use \u instead of \x, right?

Comment: So I take it you want to strip out everything except printable ASCII/Basic Latin?

Comment: Also curious why you'd want to keep __\n__ when you are removing every other character related to line breaking, wouldn't it be simpler to remove __\n__ as well?

Comment: @Andj Yes that would conclude what I want, even ASCII will do, to be specific my goal is to remove funny characters. My code processes raw text, when dealing with texts with tabs, funny spaces in other languages, or unprintable characters, I need to convert them to ASCII `space` before further processing it.

Comment: It will also remove punctuation, since a lot of English punctuation exists outside of the Basic Latin range, it will remove letters from English loanwords with characters outside basic Latin. Ultimately it comes down to the source of the raw text, what domains the text covers, which countries the text is from.

Comment: @Andj I would say it's less of a language thing but more of a text-based sequence, so punctuation sits in the removing list, your comment gives me insight to further improve the regex expression, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified regex expression inspired by Carlo Arenas' answer.

Code:

```py
import re

def replace_unknown_characters_with_space(input_string):
    # Replace all non printable ascii, excluding \n from the expression
    cleaned_string = re.sub(r'[^\x20-\x7E\n]', ' ', input_string, flags=re.DOTALL)

    return cleaned_string

def main():
    test_string = "This is a test string with some unprintable characters:\nHello\x85World\x0DThis\nis\x2028a\x2029test."
    
    print("Original String:")
    print(test_string)
    
    cleaned_string = replace_unknown_characters_with_space(test_string)
    
    print("\nCleaned String:")
    print(cleaned_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output

```
Original String:
This is a test string with some unprintable characters:
Hello
Thisd
is 28a 29test.

Cleaned String:
This is a test string with some unprintable characters:
Hello World This
is 28a 29test.
```

`\n` is no longer replaced

Answer (score 1):

You don't need *re* for this. You can use built-in functionality.

Just build a translation table and then str.translate()

For example:

```
TEST_STRING = "This is a test string with some unprintable characters:\nHello\x85World\x0DThis\x0Ais\x2028a\x2029test."
TDICT = {c: " " for c in range(32) if c != 10}
print(TEST_STRING.translate(TDICT))
```

**Output:**

```
This is a test string with some unprintable characters:
Hello
World This
is 28a 29test.
```

**Note:**

*re* is **much** faster than *str.translate* once you've discerned the correct regular expression

Comment: Nice one;) What a about `dict.fromkeys((c for c in range(32) if c != 10), " ")`?

Comment: @cards dict.fromkeys is significantly slower than the dictionary comprehension in this case

Answer (score 0):

The question seem to have multiple parts so lets address them independently

**Why is '\n' affected?**

'\n' is a special character for regular expressions, as they are designed to operate in lines and '\n' indicates the end of the line.

As you had found, you might as well include '\n' in the text you want to match but then need to make the RE engine aware that it shouldn't treat it specially and for that you can use the `re.DOTALL` flag.

**What do you mean by "printable"?**

"printable" has a wider meaning than what ChatGPT suggested and that seem to be a translation of the POSIX ASCII class [:print:] (I would have recommended [:graph:] instead) to Python; it would seem from your test that you might had been more interested on removing "funny characters" that would affect the output when printed.

Your test includes characters, probably mistranslated by ChatGPT, for UTF-8 spaces (`\s` is a better option to identify those in a Regex and Python doesn't use \x for codepoints bigger than 255 but instead uses \u with similar numbers, so they were probably from PCRE syntax)

Since you include UTF-8 spaces, and python strings are UTF-8 it might seem logical to also filter out "funny UTF-8 characters" like the BIDI control class, which would have a similar effect than '\r' if you are planning on printing that string later.

If you consider any non ASCII character as "funny" then the solution will need to change as well.

The following version of your example (with the corrected test text and some expansion) could be considered "correct" but I suspect would require further changes as you refine your requirements.

```py
import re

def replace_unknown_characters_with_space(input_string):
    # Replace non-printable ASCII characters (including escape sequences) with spaces
    cleaned_string = re.sub(r'[^][\w\n!"\#$%&\'()*+,./:;<=>?@\\\^_`{|}~-]', ' ', input_string, flags=re.DOTALL)

    return cleaned_string

def main():
    test_string = "This is a test string with some unprintable characters:\nHello\x85World\x0AThis\x0Dis\u2028a\u2029test. including some punctuation like `({~})' and even \\, and \" + words like <año> or numbers like \u1bb1\nText cant be \033[1m[bold]\033[0m or go \u2067backwards\u2069, but can also contain wide numbers like \uff11 or ０"

    print("Original String:")
    print(test_string)

    cleaned_string = replace_unknown_characters_with_space(test_string)

    print("\nCleaned String:")
    print(cleaned_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This replaces printable characters like `(` or `"` with spaces.

Comment: @user2357112: good point, but I though the biggest contribution from my answer still stands which is: "use a expression that identifies what you want, include '\n', and negate it and don't forget DOTALL"

Answer (score -1):

Do the opposite, and skip `\x0A`

```
def replace_unknown_characters_with_space(input_string):
    # Replace non-printable characters (including escape sequences) with spaces
    # According to ChatGPT, \n should not be in this range
    cleaned_string = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x09\x11-\x1F]', ' ', input_string)

    return cleaned_string
```

Comment: This returns an empty string given OP's *test_string*

Comment: This replaces everything *but* a few control characters with spaces.

Comment: However, if you fix the error, this is exactly the right answer. Newline `\x0a` is one of the characters OP changed to space; the fix is to exclude it from the regex.